# When I attempt to export a calendar, nothing at all happens.

Tags: calendar

Is there a common bug or reason that export from calendar should not work? The .ics file simply does not appear anywhere. Also, when I attempt to email a .ics file with calendar the system cannot find the /tmp/calendar.ics file. Is this a common problem? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug, you can mark "it affects me as well" in the bug tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maya/+bug/1355090